# How to check the operating system of a server remotely?

Tags: linux

Is there a tool that takes an IP address and outputs the operating system of that machine?

Comment: I don't think any such tool to determine OS type solely from IP address exists.  `nmap` could give you its best guess.

Comment: I'm sorry. should have searched better.
http://superuser.com/questions/164193/how-to-detect-os-of-remote-server

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's called [nmap](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html). Keep in mind that you should have permission from the owner of the remote system before running tools like this against it.

```
nmap -O
```

Comment: Kind of. `nmap` will take its best guess. It's usually fairly accurate but it can be wrong. It's impossible to tell with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like `nmap` to do this.
However, make sure you know the local laws before running a tool like nmap. It is prohibited to use such tools without the explicit permission of the network administrator even on your office network.

```
nmap -O
```

The -O option does operating system “fingerprinting”. Nmap version 5.50 has 2,982 OS fingerprints and 7,319 version-detection signatures.

For more information on using nmap, refer to:
http://www.linuxforu.com/tag/advanced-nmap-series/

Answer (score 0):

The nmap is the way of recognizing the system remotely when you dont want to establish connection with it. It is an active/agressive fingerprinting.

There is also a great tool for passive fingerprinting called p0f. It has been developed by lcamtuf and it anylyze the trafic between you and the server based on regular connection stream.

If you are able to connect to the server on some port like http i would suggest p0f. It's not invasive and will not triger snort or any IDP/IPS/Firewall on the way.